# 502 Bad Gateway Error when accessing Google Firebase Hosting from Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, firebase

I'm running into a 502 Bad Gateway Error when wanting to access static files hosted on Google Firebase Hosting from a Node.js app hosted on Google App Engine. When accessing the same files from my local machine, everything is working fine. All the CORS headers are defined properly.

Am I missing something else, like an access key for Firebase or so? I believe the problem might lie with my `app.yaml` deployment file.

[image: 502 bad gateway]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem myself! Since most middleware is not bundled with Express any more, it was necessary to manually add the package for my EJS views in `package.json`.